# Not an editor command: RopeGotoDefinition

Tags: vim, python-mode

I'm working with a fresh install of python-mode (installed with Vundle on Vim 8) and find that "go to definition" mapping never works no matter how I set `g:pymode_rope_goto_definition_bind`.

Then I found `RopeGotoDefinition` is not an editor command. How could this happen? I'm confused.

Comment: This is not a programming question; this is application support.

Comment: @melpomene oops sorry, but I really want to get some help.

Comment: Probably came from a plugin you used to use.  Perhaps one called `pymode`.  Quick search for "vim pymode plugin" revealed this: https://github.com/python-mode/python-mode

Comment: @christian-gibbons yeah I'm using the plugin from exactly this source.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by myself before someone thinks I can't even do a `git clone`.

After digging into the plugin code, I found `g:pymode_rope_goto_definition_bind` is actually mapped to `:call pymode#rope#goto_definition()<CR>` rather than `:RopeGotoDefinition` which appears only once in the whole repo.

After verifying `:call pymode#rope#goto_definition()<CR>` command works as expected, I found my problem (failing to map) was caused by terminal emulator and Vim eating up all <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>letter</kbd> combinations. Something other than that works well, e.g. `let g:pymode_rope_goto_definition_bind='<leader>pg'`.

As for `:RopeGotoDefinition`, maybe it's just the remnant of old code lingering in the documentation.